# Header logo magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have an issue in backend header logo upload image, image is not uloading. in magento2
Please find the scrrenshot below:
http://prntscr.com/fscxw6

Thanks

Comment: Please check directory permission

Comment: Yes, thanks it is 777 permission for pub director

Answer (score 1):

**You should set as bellow recommended.**

cd your Magento install dir

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

I hope this will help you.